# How to get and store a network name

Tags: c, windows, system

Is there a way to get a WiFi/network name name that the computer I'm running the program on is connected, and then later on that same name is used in a `system()` function. I'm making a program to find the WiFi key when run on another Windows computer and then store it in a .txt file. Code:

```
system("netsh wlan show profile WiFi_name_here key=clear >%USERPROFILE%\\Desktop\\key.txt");
```

P.S. I won't really store the actual file on Desktop this is just for test.

Comment: @selbie not quite what I was looking for, don't see a way I could "insert" the network name in code

Comment: What do you mean by "wifi key"?  You mean the SSID or the password required to connect to that network?  Are you trying to retrieve this information or just asking how to save data to a file?

Comment: By "wifi key"I meant a program that will find the password of a connected network, and I made the program but it only works on my system(it will work on yours too if you are using windows and replace wifi_name_here with your SSID) but right now I'm looking for a way to get the SSID from a different computer when running the program and then use it the the given line of code

Comment: Igor, I think what you are saying is that you want to extract the ssid and key from a remote computer and apply it to the local computer.  Or are you saying that you want to extract the SSID/key from the local and apply it to a remote computer? I'm confused.

Comment: I want to extract the ssid and key from a remote computer and apply it to the remote computer. Sorry for complicating things earlier on :D

Comment: I'm even more confused. ***What are you really trying to do?***

Comment: Hahah. Lets say I own PC1 which is connected to WiFi1. And I transfer a program to the PC2 which is connected to WiFi2. Note: WiFi1 != WiFi2. When I run the program on PC2 I want to : 1.Get the SSID so the program can proceed getting the key  2. Get the WiFi key and store it to lets say Local Disk on PC2 in a .txt file.   Did I make it a bit more understandable or? :)

Comment: No, I'm still confused.  You've already got a script that copy your network settings to a file, so what are you asking that you don't already know how to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155673/discussion-between-igor-pavkovic-and-selbie).